# Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix having complex entries where all the real and imaginary parts of the entries of A are rational.

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, number-theory

Does there exists at least one non nilpotent matrix $A$, which is a square matrix (of order $\geq2$) having complex entries where all the real and imaginary parts of the entries of A are rational and there exists some power of $A$, say $k$ for which $A^k$ is a matrix having complex entries but this time real, imaginary parts are some integers?

Comment: This isn't even true for 1-by-1 matrices.

Comment: Try looking at $A^2$ when $A$ is a 2-by-2 matrix, say with elements $a,b,c,d$. If $a$ is rational and not an integer, can $a^2$ be an integer? What can you say from that?

Comment: but $a^2$ is not an entry of $A^2$.

Comment: and I need an example just one example or we have to show that such type of example never exist

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear: any matrix $A$ with integer coefficients would meet your requirements as stated. If the real and imaginary parts of the $(A)_{ij}$ are required to be in $\Bbb{Q} \setminus \Bbb{Z}$, then a nilpotent matrix like $\pmatrix{c & -c \\ c & -c}$ where $c = 1/2 + i/2$ would fit the bill.

Comment: ok.thanks..does there exists one which is not nilpotent?

Comment: @– Rob Arthan , your matrix is nilpotent always for any value of $c$, so this will not answer the problem

Comment: @SibeswarDutta: why not?

Comment: see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, suppose $n=m^2$ is a perfect square. Let $A=\frac{1+i}{m}E$, where $E$ denotes the matrix of ones. It is not nilpotent, as it is a nonzero scalar multiple of a nonzero real symmetric matrix $E$. However, $A^2=\frac{(1+i)^2}{m^2}E^2=\frac{2i}{n}(nE)=2iE$ is a matrix whose entries are all equal to $2i$.

If you want the matrix to be nonsingular, consider $A+mI$ instead. It is nonsingular as its spectrum consists of a simple eigenvalue $m(2+i)$ as well as an eigenvalue $m$ of multiplicity $n-1$. Now
\begin{aligned}
(A+mI)^2
&=A^2+2mA+m^2I\\
&=2iE+2(1+i)E+m^2I\\
\end{aligned}
is a matrix whose entries are Gaussian integers.

Comment: Thank you @user 1551. Is it possible to construct  $A$ such that $\det(A)\neq0$

Comment: @SibeswarDutta Please see my new edit.